# how do I label my images for computer vision

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, computer-vision, ann

So I want to do shape recognition task on a flowchart using CNN, but my input images are not labeled and I don't know how to do that automaticaly I mean not manually, anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I will make it clearer. So, my input data is flowchart images and I want to do feature extraction from theses flowcharts. Since, I want to use CNN for this, I need to have labeled data but it's not the case and I don't want how to label them